# How to make pandas.read_excel with engine='openpyxl' behave like it did with xlrd, not showing nanoseconds by default?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

We have a process that reads data in from an Excel .xlsx spreadsheet into a pandas DataFrame.  While trying to upgrade to the latest version (1.2.1) of pandas, I saw the following in the doc for pandas `read_excel` function for the `engine` argument:

> - “openpyxl” supports newer Excel file formats.

> Changed in version 1.2.0: The engine xlrd now only supports old-style .xls files.

So, I added `engine='openpyxl'` to my `read_excel` function call and started to see strange, new behavior, whereby datetime values now were showing nanoseconds by default, which wasn't the case with `xlrd`.  On top of that, I was seeing datetimes a bit off from the expected value seen in Excel by a few nanoseconds. I saw the same thing with pandas 1.2.1 and also 1.1.4.

For the following Excel data *(the raw values show as 44098.0416666667 for the 9/24 date and 44083.6847222222 for both 9/9 dates)*

[image]

I'm seeing the following behavior:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_excel('~/testDatetimeNanos.xlsx')
             TestDate
0 2020-09-24 01:00:00
1 2020-09-09 16:26:00
2 2020-09-09 16:26:00
>>> pd.read_excel('~/testDatetimeNanos.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
                    TestDate
0 2020-09-24 01:00:00.000003
1 2020-09-09 16:25:59.999998
2 2020-09-09 16:26:00.000000
```

**I'm wondering if there's a way to use the new openpyxl engine so that its behavior is consistent with the old xlrd engine...?**
*Also, wondering if I may have stumbled onto a bug (update: submitted [bug report](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39599)).*

**As of openpyxl ≥3.0.7, the bug has been fixed (Aug 2021)**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as the underlying bug is now fixed

Comment: And don't forget @JeffG, excel is restricted to 15 digits and rounds the 16th+ digits.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the engine and the version of openpyxl, you can simply remove the nanoseconds like this:

```
df['testDate'] = df['testDate'].str[:-7]

#              testDate
#0  2020-09-24 01:00:00
#1  2020-09-09 16:25:59
#2  2020-09-09 16:26:00
```